# Set up autorotate of screen in 18.10 with Wayland

Tags: 18.10, display-rotation

I tried following [this guide](https://linuxappfinder.com/blog/auto_screen_rotation_in_ubuntu) which apparently worked back in 2016. Is there an equivalent method that might work with Wayland? I saw somewhere that Gnome now supports it but my display settings only show a way to set the screen orientation manually.

Answer (score -1):

The good old `xrandr -o [rotation]` won't work in Ubuntu 18.

The working command to rotate screen in Ubuntu 18 is

```
xrandr --output [display port] --rotate [rotation]
```

with

- `[rotation]` being, as before, one of `normal`, `left`, `right` or `inverted`;
- `[display port]`: unless you already know yours (HDMI, DP, eDP...), you can

  - run `xrandr` alone and read through what it says to find the one which is said to be *connected*;

    or
  - run `xrandr | egrep -o '^.+ connected' | cut -d " " -f 1` to have Shell bring it to you.

    With the two commands put together, you have:

    ```
    o=$(xrandr | egrep -o '^.+ connected' | cut -d " " -f 1); xrandr --output $o --rotate [rotation]
    ```

    or

    ```
    xrandr --output $(xrandr | egrep -o '^.+ connected' | cut -d " " -f 1) --rotate [rotation]
    ```

Comment: How is this supposed to work under Wayland?